# In asp.net Web API, ModelStates is invalid when the reference types is null?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have this class

```
public class ClassA {
  public int AProp{get;set;}
 }

public class RequestObject{
  public int Id {get;set;}

  public ClassA TestProp{get;set;}

 //Some other porperties
}
```

When I send the request JSON to the server with TestProp `null`, I get the following error message:

```
{
   "Message": "The request is invalid.",
    "ModelState": {
     "request.TestProp": ["The TestProp field is required."],

 }
}
```

Why am I getting this error when I have not put any `[Required]` attribute? 
How can I get away with the problem? (Without having to use `?` as I cannot change the `class` itlself)

Comment: Have you tried **DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes = false;** in your **Application_Start** ?

Comment: Nope. @rad, but my problem is with Reference types.